# What is a way to force my code to wait inside a promise?

Tags: node.js

so I currenlty know what the issue is, it's the fact that my await here `var contacBID = await ContactIDFinder.findingBoondIDcontact(ContactHID)` can not be used here. But he problem is: I need to wait in order to avoid just getting a promise, and this has to include a Promise since it will also be used later with a promise. Any ideas? Feel free to call my code ugly, I know it is, but any help is appreciated, thanks!

````
    var optionsA = {
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://example.com",
        qs: { hapikey: "smthng" }
    };
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        request(optionsA, function (error, response, body) {

        if(error){
            logResponse("could not reach boondmanager status:",response.statusCode);
            reject("error while reading");
            }

        else{
            var dealH = JSON.parse(body);
            if(dealH.associations.associatedVids[0] != undefined){
                var ContactHID = dealH.associations.associatedVids[0]
                var contacBID = await ContactIDFinder.findingBoondIDcontact(ContactHID)
                console.log(`attempt at finding the BID for the contact linked to the company led to : ${contacBID}`)
                if (contacBID != null) { 
                    console.log("associated BID is : "+ contacBID)
                }
                else{
                    console.log("linked with a contact unsynchronized")
                }
            }
            else{
                console.log("Not linked at all with a contact")
                resolve(null)
            }
            resolve(contacBID);
            }
        });
        });
}```
````

Comment: request is deprecated since 2 years now, maybe you should look into new package to do your request. Axios and fetch manage promises by default and are not deprecated. It'll look way more clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* use `await` there if you mark the enclosing function as async.

Change:

```
request(optionsA, function (error, response, body) {
```

to:

```
request(optionsA, async function (error, response, body) {
```

Comment: This works! Thank you very much! Will mark it as anwser as soon as possible